# ASP.NET MVC 4 route username / action issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am currently working on an asp.net mvc 4 application and I have the need for the following type of urls:

**Urls that need to be routed**

> 1. http://www.mysite.com/foo/user1     <------- {username}
> 2. http://www.mysite.com/foo/edit
> 3. http://www.mysite.com/foo/delete/1
> 4. http://www.mysite.com/bar/user1     <------- {username}
> 5. http://www.mysite.com/bar/edit
> 6. http://www.mysite.com/bar/delete/1

The issue I'm having is that currently {username} gets treated as an action so to work around the problem I implemented the following routes, but this would mean that every time I want to implement a new action, or have a controller that needs {username}, I would have to update my routes:

**Only Foo routes shown**

```
routes.MapRoute("FooSomeAction", "foo/someaction", new { controller = "Food", action = "SomeAction" });            
routes.MapRoute("FooDelete", "foo/delete/{id}", new { controller = "Food", action = "Delete" });            


routes.MapRoute(
    "FooProfile",
    "foo/{username}",
    new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index", username = "" }
);


// Default route
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**2 Questions**

1) Is there any way I can achieve the above urls without hardcoding all the routes?

2) What is the best way to handle a situation where someone uses a username that happens to be the same name as a controller or action name?

DotnetShadow

Comment: Your second question, as far as I know, isn't possible. What's so bad about having the action in there too?

Comment: What's so bad about having the action in there too? – Sorry, What did you mean by this?

Comment: Apologies if I was vague, I mean is it possible that you can have the action and controller name both present in the link? Something like /User/Edit/User1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom route constraint that would check if the username exists in the possible actions for the controller. If it finds an action match, it fails and will use your default route (Edit for example).  You may want to cache the list for performance reasons, but I leave that up to you.

```
    private static List<Type> GetSubClasses<T>()
    {
        return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
            type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))).ToList();
    }

    public static  List<string> GetActionNames(string controllerName)
    {
        controllerName = controllerName + "Controller";
        var controller = GetSubClasses<Controller>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == controllerName);

        var names = new List<string>();
        if (controller != null)
        {
            var methods = controller.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (var info in methods)
            {
                if (info.ReturnType == typeof(ActionResult))
                {
                    names.Add(info.Name);
                }
            }

        }
        return names;
    }


    public class UsernameNotAction : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match
            (
                HttpContextBase httpContext,
                Route route,
                string parameterName,
                RouteValueDictionary values,
                RouteDirection routeDirection
            )
        {
            int i = 0;
            var username = values["username"];
            var actionList =  GetActionNames(values["controller"].ToString());

            return !actionList.Any(a => a.ToUpper() == username.ToString().ToUpper());
        }
    }


    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "FooProfile",
            "{controller}/{username}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index2", username = "" },
            new { IsParameterAction = new UsernameNotAction() }
        );
        // Default route
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: That's a very interesting solution. You definately don't want to do a database call everytime you navigate, but he could store a list of usernames in the session. I'm not really sure I like it, but I'll +1 for originality and a cool idea.

Comment: Good Stuff Mark, I was actually thinking of some sort of constraint, but I was worried about performance too. Thanks for the alternative approach

Comment: It's not actually doing a database call - it's testing if the action is in the controller using reflection (may actually be worse for performance but who knows)

Comment: Ahh I just read the description. I see, so you'd do basically  User.Identity.Username and check that against the actions/controllers. Very clever.

Comment: Quite clever actually I wonder if this approach has been used before by others, obviously you must of used it or know how to write it off the top of your head :-P

Comment: Mark, could you please tell me about "IsParameterAction" in the constraint is that a reserved word? I'm trying to find documentation on it? Is it the same as saying new { action = new UsernameNotAction() } ?

Comment: It's the same, the name of the constraint doesn't really matter (think about it like you can name your variable whatever you want) only the value does - in this case UsernameNotAction()

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really the answer you're looking for, sorry.

1) There's no way to route that way. There's nothing to differentiate those routes from one another, other than what you've done. I have to question why this is even necessary, I'm sure you have a good reason, but it makes no sense to me. You're still using the Index action, so why not just /foo/index/username. All I can come up with, is you have no control over the url for some reason.

2) If you use the default route, there's no problem. With your routing, problem. Your only real option is to make your controller and action names reserved words (prevent users from being created with those usernames in the database).

Sorry I couldn't really help you.

Comment: Good point about 1) having index as the action, it just looks cleaner having /foo/username I guess

Basically my idea was if you were viewing someones profile publicly I would have:
/profile/username
/friends/username
/gallery/username

but if I'm in my own profile I would just do
/profile/edit/1
/friends/list
/gallery/delete/1

If that makes sense?

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but the default routing that works for 83.57% of all cases is controller/action/view. If you want to break that pattern, you're generating work for yourself, so just ask yourself if it's worth all the effort vs what you gain. IMO.

Comment: Also, people shouldn't be navigating your site by modifying the url, those are going to come via actionlinks and such and really, does anyone look at the url or care what it looks like? http://mysite/viewusers/index/bob1111 vs http://mysite/viewusers/bob1111, who will really care? :)

Comment: I agree that actionlinks is how someone will navigate around the site, it's more about the initial public profile page more than anything.

If you think of it in terms of someone visiting a website usually u would use www.mysite.com not www.mysite.com/index.html

But I agree with what you are saying, and yes 14.43% isn't worth it

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that unless you route every single route and that is not the best way to go.

What's so wrong in having the Action name in it?

Comment: What's so wrong in having the controller name in it? - What do you mean by this?

Comment: I meant the Action name

By doing

http://www.mysite.com/bar/user1 

This will map to the Controller : bar and Action user1

You wanted to hit Controller : bar Action : Index but that's not how  MVC routes work

You need to do something like

http://www.mysite.com/bar/ActionName/user1